# Biholomorphic map between $\mathbb {C}$ minus an interval and minus a point

Tags: complex-analysis

Decide if $\mathbb{C}-[a,b]$ is biholomorphic to  $\mathbb{C}-{p}$, where $[a,b]$ is an interval of $\mathbb {R}\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $p$ is a point in $\mathbb{C}$.

I suspect that this could be true, it is easy to see that they are homotopic and I hope that they are homeomorphic but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Could you please say something about the tools available to you? (That is, this appears to be a homework question; if so, what type of course is this, and what theorems have you seen recently?)

Comment: is not a homework question but is related to one. Any tool from basic complex analysis is allow

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb C - [a,b]$ can be mapped conformally to a bounded domain, in particular to $\mathbb D - 0$ (where $\mathbb D$ is the open unit disk).  But
$\mathbb C - p$ can not: if $f$ is a bounded holomorphic function on it,
$p$ is a removable singularity, and then Liouville's theorem says $f$ is constant.

Comment: and if $f(z)$ isn't bounded near $p$, then it is bounded as $z \to \infty$ and has a pole of order $1$ at $p$, so $f(z) = \frac{cz+d}{z-p}$ and it doesn't map $\mathbb{C}-1 $ to $\mathbb{C} - [a,b]$

Comment: how is the conformal map from $C-[a,b]$ to $D-{0}$?

Comment: For simplicity let's take $a=0$, $b=1$.  Then $f(z) = \dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-1/z}} - 1$.